# Working with sets and its laws

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Given:

> $(A \oplus B) \cup C = (A \cap C) \oplus ( B - C )$

Work with algebra of sets to prove the proposition above is true.

In order to give a solution to this problem I've done the process below, but I reached the point where I don't know how to handle the laws.

> $(A \oplus B) \cup C = [(A - B) \cup (B - A)] \cup C $
>
> $(A \oplus B) \cup C = [(A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)] \cup C $
>
> $(A \oplus B) \cup C = [( (A \cap B^c) \cup B) \cap ((A \cap B^c)\cup
>  C)] \cup C $
>
> $(A \oplus B) \cup C = [(A \cap U) \cap ((A \cap B^c)\cup C)] \cup C $
>
> $(A \oplus B) \cup C = [(A ) \cap ((A\cap B^c)\cup C)] \cup C $

I'm not certain whether I've followed the right track or it's by far wrong.
Any help would be very welcomed. How should I continue solving it?

Comment: What do you mean by $A\oplus B$?

Comment: @AbishankaSahathat that symbol stands for symmetric difference of sets. It's also represented by a triangle between the two sets identifiers.

Comment: @rickHdz: what is the idea beyond the primed identifiers?

Comment: @Lehs It stands for the complement of a set. At least, that's how I was taught. Perhaps if I change that notation it'll be more readable and understandable.

Comment: @rickHdz: I'm just slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an algebraic machinery that always work for set algebra:

1. transform to expression only with $\cap$ and $\oplus$ and a universe $U$ that is a super set to all sets in the expression.
2. replace $\cap$ with $\cdot$, $\oplus$ with $+$, $\emptyset$ with $0$ and $U$ with $1$ (optional)
3. do the usual algebraical simplifications, adding the rules $A+A=0$ and $A\cdot A=A$
4. transform back to optional operators

In your case:

$(A+B)\cup C=AC+(B-C)\Leftrightarrow (A+B)+C+(A+B)C=AC+B(1+C)\Leftrightarrow$
$A+B+C+AC+BC=AC+B+BC\Leftrightarrow A+C=0\Leftrightarrow A=C$